# Client hosting on Amazon EC2 with Cloudfront for content

Tags: wordpress, plesk, amazon

I have a server on Amazon EC2 with a few different clients. It is a Plesk server. Most of them use WordPress. Is it possible to store their WWW data on a cloudfront account while retaining the server settings and everything else on the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 1):

Cloudfront is a CDN.  It will pull content from your EC2 server (or any other server) to multiple geographic locations around the us.  Its only purpose is to speed up your site.  It really only works properly for static content.  (JavaScript, images, CSS).   You can't move all your www data from EC2 to Cloudfront.

If your www data is all static, (which in the case of WordPress it is not) then you can use another Amazon product (Amazon S3, simple storage) to store your complete site.  Amazon S3 allows what it calls website buckets.  You can also put Cloudfront in front of S3 to speed up those buckets.

The only thing I can think of which would take some scripting is to write a script that downloads your WordPress site (spiders it), and copies all assets to s3.   Then you put Cloudfront on top of s3.  This would probably make things perform quickly, since you are not exactly running PHP for every request, but would take away the instant update WordPress.   This would be similar to what a reverse caching proxy does.  The bottom line is you really cannot get rid of EC2 or some other hosting account if you want to have WordPress running with its intended functionality.